# Error on heroku open

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, heroku

I'm following this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#specify-dependencies-with-pip), and when I execute the `heroku open` command, I get a very long series of error/warning messages (you can see below)

```
(venv)me:~/Desktop/django-projects/hellodjango$ heroku openOpening arcane-everglades... done
(venv)me:~/Desktop/django-projects/hellodjango$ 
(process:29722): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
get_contentWindow@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:412:54
get_securityUI@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:662:17
browser_XBL_Constructor@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:786:17
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
```

What is the problem?

Thanks for any help !

### Edit :

I noticed Ubuntu was opening the website with Firefox, I changed the default browser to Chrome, and the message (after `heroku open`) changed to this :

```
1424792784910   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net: ReferenceError: sss is not defined (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///usr/share/mozilla/extensions/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net/bootstrap.js:72:4) JS Stack trace: shutdown@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///usr/share/mozilla/extensions/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/webapps-team@bootstrap.js:72:5 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4436:9 < shutdownObserver@XPIProvider.jsm:2183:13
[Child 30003] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset by peer: file /build/buildd/firefox-35.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 451
```

Comment: Seems like a disconnect between your browser and heroku (local). You don't NEED to run heroku open, its just a short-cut to the URL

Comment: I know, I just wondered if I messed something up. Strangely, after a few tries, the messages went away. Maybe the dyno was asleep?

Comment: I sometimes have to start the dyno if it is a newly created app on heroku